# Packet loss calculate in Flex

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, networking, packet-loss

How I can calculate **packet loss** from **Flex**. 
Any Idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible in Flex. From the [Flex Docs:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html)

> Packets lost in transmission are not retransmitted, or even detected.

Consider using TCP instead of UDP if your application requires guaranteed packet delivery.

Comment: Thank you. I am developing internet speed test app on flex. I need to calculate, Download speed, Upload speed, Latency (Round Trip Time), Jitter, Packet loss and Network availability. Everything OK except Latency and Packet loss. How can I measure those ? Please help me.

Comment: [NetStreamInfo](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStreamInfo.html) should get you started on getting such QoS data - you will need an RTMP server though.